# Dell XPS Developer Edition - upgrade breaks wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, dell

I just got a brand new Dell XPS 13 laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed. Everything works like it's supposed to, but doing an `apt-get dist-upgrade` causes the wifi to stop working. At that point, I can still connect to the net by plugging my phone in and turning on tethering, so I know it's a problem with the wifi, and not networking in general. Restoring the system from the rescue partition fixes the problem.

Any ideas on what's happening? Or at least ideas on how to narrow down the search? I tried Dell's tech support, and they weren't very helpful.

- Model: XPS 13 9350 Developer Edition
- Ubuntu version: 14.04
- Kernel: 3.19.0-33-generic

Comment: My guess that package with Wi-Fi firmware being removed upon upgrade, and you need to install it manually. Try to execute `sudo apt install linux-firmware`, and see if it fixes the problem. If not, post `dmesg` output here.

Comment: Honestly, it would be a bug, if you ask me. But I can also assume that firmware were put not with package, but manually by Dell, then the result is predictable.

Comment: Found the answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/799661/has-3-19-0-65-introduced-new-secure-boot-requirements-to-14-04-lts Summary: when installing kernel 3.19.0-65, it's necessary to disable that satanic spawn known as "UEFI Secure Boot".

Comment: Great, you may probably want to post an answer yourself. It seems, that wi-fi firmware — which is a third-party driver — isn't signed. Btw, I think your `dmesg` should mention it in some way, then it would be nice to add in the answer.